# Resizing div with js from flash makes flash appear to freeze in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3

I have flash resizing it's container div by using external interface to call the javascript:

```
function expandbottomNav() {
        document.getElementById('bottomNav').style.height = '400px';
    }
function shrinkbottomNav() {
        document.getElementById('bottomNav').style.height = '31px';
    }
```

Now this appears to work fine in every browser except chrome. For some reason after the div is shrunk back down to size, the flash player looks like it's frozen. It's actually not frozen because if you resize the window the flash player starts playing again and you can see it had made progress since it appeared frozen. This only happens in chrome. Does anyone have any idea why something like this might happen?

The site so you can check it out yourself(yes I know it's a broken mess in IE, but I'm kind of ignoring that for now):

> removed<

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. I've tried different window modes but that doesn't help. The problem is when it resizes the div back down because if I comment that line out the flash never appears to freeze. But I need to be able to resize the div...

Comment: it isn't frozen, the string is moving at normal speed but is rendered only when i move mouse cursor over it. did you try setting `object height` to certain amount of pixels each time the div is resized? and did you try scale='exactfit'?

Comment: Make this into an answer so I can give you credit for being correct. Resizing the object height each time fixed the "freeze". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome ;)

> it isn't frozen, the string is moving
>   at normal speed but is rendered only
>   when i move mouse cursor over it. did
>   you try setting object height to
>   certain amount of pixels each time the
>   div is resized? and did you try
>   scale='exactfit'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this but I remember that the "freeze" issue in Flash - in some browsers - was related to the return statement of the external JS functions.

Try to add something like `return true;` in your JS functions.

Ciao!